# Cannot convert json to object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, json-deserialization

Hello i've got this error Message

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ClassLibraryMifosX.ViewModels.Rootobject2' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JS

my deserialize code :

```
Rootobject Rsc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

my class with json object description:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Class1> Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int entityId { get; set; }
    public string entityAccountNo { get; set; }
    public string entityExternalId { get; set; }
    public string entityName { get; set; }
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string parentName { get; set; }
    public string entityMobileNo { get; set; }
    public Entitystatus entityStatus { get; set; }
}

public class Entitystatus
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

my json :

```
[
  {
    "entityId": 1,
    "entityAccountNo": "000000001",
    "entityExternalId": "100001-241563",
    "entityName": "Smith W R",
    "entityType": "CLIENT",
    "parentId": 1,
    "parentName": "Head Office",
    "entityMobileNo": "254728000000",
    "entityStatus": {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "clientStatusType.active",
      "value": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    "entityId": 310,
    "entityAccountNo": "000000310",
    "entityName": "John Smith",
    "entityType": "CLIENT",
    "parentId": 14,
    "parentName": "TestOffice1",
    "entityStatus": {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "clientStatusType.active",
      "value": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    "entityId": 422,
    "entityAccountNo": "000000422",
    "entityExternalId": "smith1",
    "entityName": "Smith Jones",
    "entityType": "CLIENT",
    "parentId": 11,
    "parentName": "Barquisimeto",
    "entityMobileNo": "88989898",
    "entityStatus": {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "clientStatusType.active",
      "value": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    "entityId": 774,
    "entityAccountNo": "000000774",
    "entityName": "John AAA Smith",
    "entityType": "CLIENT",
    "parentId": 1,
    "parentName": "Head Office",
    "entityStatus": {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "clientStatusType.active",
      "value": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    "entityId": 1789,
    "entityAccountNo": "Head Office000001789",
    "entityExternalId": "547222",
    "entityName": "Kaitlin Smith",
    "entityType": "CLIENT",
    "parentId": 1,
    "parentName": "Head Office",
    "entityStatus": {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "clientStatusType.active",
      "value": "Active"
    }
  }
]
```

what i have been done wrongly ? Thanks

Comment: Since the root object in the json is an array you need to deserialize into a `Class1[]`, or a `List<Class1>`, not an object containing a property, there is no `Property1` in your json. So try just `DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no root object into your Json data so just deserialize it as a collection of `Class1` like below:

```
var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);
```

Don't forget that VS can create for you a class that can be used to deserailize your Json data. You don't need to write yourself the definition of `Class1`. Just go to menu => **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes**

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark it as an accepted answer if it helps you ;-)

Comment: vs has created this class for me but for next time i understand this difference between deserializing into an array or an object

Answer (score 0):

The first and last character of your JSON is a square bracket `[ ]` rather than a curly bracket `{ }`. This means that it is an array, not an object. In order to parse it, you need to deserialize it into an *array* of `Class1` objects:

```
Class1[] Rsc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);
```

If you wanted to use a `Rootobject` object instead, you could then use it like so:

```
Rootobject root = new RootObject();
root.Property1 = new List<Class1>(Rsc);
```